# What happened to the artwork of SO?

Tags: discussion, images

When visiting Stack Overflow today, I noticed that the crosses to delete favoured tags et al. have been changed: they look higher (too high) now and when hovering over them, I get larger crosses than before:

[image]

Moreover, I noticed the envelope (notifying me of new replies, comments, etc.) has been changed, too (it has a more distinctive look, now). Are there other elements that have been changed lately? Or is this some kind of bug?

Comment: Hasn't it been like this for a while?

Comment: @Jon: No, I only noticed this today. And, looking at the revision number (2010.5.9.4), I suspect this change was indeed made today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're rebuilding the graphics to have proper PNG alpha channels as [part of the CSS Zen Garden exercise](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/whats-wrong-with-css.html).

Answer (score 5):

The revision number on SO (at the bottom right, in the footer) has changed to `2010.5.9.4` so I'm guessing it was part of an update.

[image: SO revision]

Comment: +1 for the FHC *(and keeping the unicorn avatar)*

Comment: @dboarman: What does FHC stand for? I can't find it (e.g., at http://www.acronymfinder.com/FHC.html)

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: [Free hand circle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)

Comment: FHC = Free Hand Circle(s)

Answer (score 2):

It does look like they're a little bit too high, I'll bet somehow <strike>this</strike> CSS similar to the following is missing:

```
img.delete {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think they *want* it centered?

Comment: Because badges and tags are centered in almost every other usage, see the tag usage counts.

Comment: @balpha: Besides that, they were centered until now. I tested Josh's CSS rule and it looks *way* better than the way those crosses look now.

Comment: @balpha: I don't know specifically that they want them centered nor that any CSS is *missing*, just that I think that CSS helps and it is odd that there is no rules for `img.delete` at all.

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` is [supposed to be used only in table cells](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html).

Comment: @voyager: The article you linked to says `vertical-align: middle` can also be used on inline elements and that's exactly what those images are. Moreover, W3C's [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) contains a paragraph about vertical alignment of inline elements.

Comment: @Marcel: AFAIK, it has poor cross browser support, but I might be wrong.